# How to fix: binary = :no operator exists which takes a RHS of const & fullName

Tags: c++, stl, operator-keyword

I am demonstrating the use of the C++ STL and ostream_iterators with sets. I have a simple class with setters/getters and constructors. Whenever I attempt to use the ostream_iterator and copy function, I receive "binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const fullName' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

I am coding in Visual Studio 2019

I have tried several variants of operator =. I have removed the & for rhs, made the function void, and wrote a more complicated version checking to see if the lhs and rhs are equal. Obviously I have Googled it, and followed the link to the MS error page. 
I also know that my set has been populated properly. I iterated over the set successfully.

Here is a snippet of my class file.

```cpp
class fullName {
protected:
    string fname;
    string lname;
public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const fullName& person) {
        out << person.lname << ", " << person.fname;
        return out;
    }

    fullName& operator = (const fullName& rhs) {

        fname = rhs.fname;
        lname = rhs.lname;
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator <(fullName lhs, fullName rhs) {
        return lhs.lname < rhs.lname;   //simple cheesy sort by last name
    }
    friend bool operator >(fullName lhs, fullName rhs) {
        return lhs.lname > rhs.lname;   //simple cheesy sort by last name
    }
};
```

The copy line generates the error.

```cpp
set <fullName, less <fullName>> people;
set <fullName>::iterator itr;
//populate from file
ostream_iterator<string> screen(cout, "\n");    //ostream object, delimiter
copy(people.begin(), people.end(), screen);
```

I expected my output to be copied to the screen as it is done when I use sets of type int or string.

Comment: The question can be improved by including the full compiler error message (including all the "notes" lines that follow) along with a [mre] consisting of required headers and code we can copy-and-paste somewhere to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `screen` is of type `ostream_iterator<string>`, you need to assign *strings* to `screen`.  Since there is no conversion from `fullName` to `string`, you get the error.

Since you are writing `fullName` objects, you should change the declartion of `screen` to

```
ostream_iterator<fullName> screen(cout, "\n");
```